# Ubuntu 16.04, Nvidia toolkit 8.0 RC, darknet compilation error: expected a ";"

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cuda

I am compiling [Darknet](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet) on Ubuntu 16.04 with GPU support.
Nvidial toolkit version 8.0 RC

And I get stuck with error:

```
nvcc --gpu-architecture=compute_52 --gpu-code=compute_52  -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wfatal-errors  -Ofast -DOPENCV -DGPU" -c ./src/convolutional_kernels.cu -o obj/convolutional_kernels.o
/usr/local/cuda/include/surface_functions.h(134): error: expected a ";"

/usr/local/cuda/include/surface_functions.h(135): error: expected a ";"

/usr/local/cuda/include/surface_functions.h(136): error: expected a ";"
```

/usr/local/cuda/include/surface_functions.h at error lines has something like this:

```
template<> __device__ __cudart_builtin__ char surf1Dread(surface<void, cudaSurfaceType1D> surf, int x, enum cudaSurfaceBoundaryMode mode) asm("__surf1Dread_char") ;
```

Any advice ?

Comment: I have a CUDA 8RC setup without OpenCV.  I downloaded the  darknet master.  This command: `nvcc --gpu-architecture=compute_52 --gpu-code=compute_52  -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wfatal-errors  -Ofast -DGPU" -c ./src/convolutional_kernels.cu -o obj/convolutional_kernels.o`   runs without any error.

Comment: what is the nvidia-cuda-toolkit version ?

Comment: I used CUDA 8RC.  `nvcc --version` reports: `Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.26`

Answer (score 15):

So it happens when your environment uses different versions of *nvcc* binary and cuda *includes* files during compilation process.

Darknet is using */usr/local/cuda/include/* as its include path
but relys on you **PATH** when executing nvcc binary. And it could belong to your another cuda installation in the system.

To avoid this force your shell to search for nvcc in the /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc.

This could be done either by hacking nvcc path in the Makefile:

**replace** NVCC=nvcc **with** NVCC=/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc

or by modyfying PATH variable for make command (simpler and session related)

```
PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH make
```

Answer (score 11):

If you have several versions of CUDA installed and need them (like me), I recommend adding the following to your (BASH) RC:

```
# DARKNET
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda8.0/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

Source your RC ('. ~/.bashrc') and complilation works!

Comment: what does this have to do with the question?

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. The cuda driver 8.0 was conflicting with nvcc version 7.5 from nvidia-cuda-dev/nvidia-cuda-toolkit from the ubuntu repo. So explicitly setting these paths and re-running `make` built everything properly against 8.0. Note: I am not building darknet, came here from google, but similar problem.

Comment: @talonmies this directly answers the compilation error question asked by the OP. In this particular case, extending the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH resolves the issue.

Answer (score 4):

This error is because of nvcc version 7.5

Looks like Cuda toolkit 8.0 RC installation via deb files does not have nvcc version 8
I have reinstalled cuda via cuda_8.0.27_linux.run installed and it works for me now

Comment: The above answer generalizes to any version of CUDA. You need to let the environment know where your installation is. Example for CUDA 9.0: `export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}};
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda9.0/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}`